# Canadian traveller problem on directed acyclic graphs

Tags: graphs, complexity-classes

What is the complexity of the [Canadian traveller problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_traveller_problem)  variant where the only thing that is seen is a single node ahead on a directed acyclic graph so that we cant go back once we go to a new node and there are some nodes that have a probability associated and we dont know the probability of others?

Comment: Please give a precise statement of your problem: I can't reconstruct it from your list of the differences to the regular CTP.  Also, I don't see how your question relates to your title. (I edited the title but I don't think I changed the sense of it at all.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby i think that ts more clear now